# loop through all fields and return false if validation of any one field fails jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing big trouble resetting the flag variables. I am not sure where I am missing :(

I have a form with lots of text fields. I am trying to loop through all the fields and on blur of each of the field I am doing some validations. If any of the validation for any of the field fails it should not submit the form. But now I am having a big trouble doing this. If I have 3 fields and the first value I have entered wrong and next two fields if I have given correct, its submitting the form which should not be. Can somebody please help me in this?

```
var globalValid = false;
var validators = {
        spacevalidation: function(val) {
        if($.trim(val) != "")
            return true;     
        else
            return false;
        },
                //Other validation fns 
};

$('#form1 .required').blur(function(){
var input = $(this);
var tmpValid = true;
input.each(function(){
    var classReturn = true;
    validatorFlag = true;
    input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
    input.removeClass('required_IE');
    if(firstTime)
    {
        input.addClass('valid');
    }
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.removeClass('valid');
        input.addClass('required');
        var $msg = $(this).attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
        globalValid = false;
    }
    else{
        if(this.className) {
            var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
            for(var p in classes) {
                if(classes[p] in validators) {
                    tmpValid = (tmpValid && validators[classes[p]] (input.val())) ? tmpValid : false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(tmpValid == false){
            input.removeClass('valid');
            input.addClass('required');
            var $msg = input.attr('title');
            input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');

        }
    }
});
```

globalValid = tmpValid;
    });

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
var returnValue = true;
if(globalValid )
{
    returnValue = true;
}
else{
    returnValue = false;
}
alert("returnValue "+returnValue);
return returnValue;
});
```

Using this code, if I put a wrong value for first field and correct value for the other two fields, ideally it should return false. But its returning true. I think I am not properly resetting the flag properly

Comment: There are way too many flags in that small piece of code..

Comment: Yes Kevin..Thats what I m confused..I am trying so many options ad literally I myself gets confused..So any elegant way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this example which provides the basic premise of what needs to occur.  Each time the blur event is fired you must validate all three fields and store the result of their validation to a global variable.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <button type="submit">Submit</form>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var globalValid = false; //Global validation flag


$("input").blur(function(){

    //local validation flag
    var tmpValid = true;

    //When one input blurs validate all of them
    $("input").each(function(){
         //notice this conditional will shortcircuit if tmpValid is false
         //this retains the state of the last validation check
         //really simple validation here, required value less than 10
         tmpValid = (tmpValid && this.value && this.value < 10) ? tmpValid:false;
    });
    //assign the result of validating all inputs to a global
    globalValid = tmpValid;
});

$("form").submit(function(e){
    //This is just here to make the fiddle work better
    e.preventDefault();

    //check the global validation flag when submitting    
    if(globalValid){
        alert("submitted");
    }else{
        alert("submit prevented");
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uC3mW/1/

Hopefully you can apply the principles in this example to your code.  The main difference is the code you have provided does not validate each input on blur.

Comment: Hi Kevin, In the above code, y is blur given first and the iterating of all inputs inside that?

Comment: @user1049057 Because the blur is used to trigger the validation.  A 'blur' represents a change of state on one of the fields, which means we need to validate every field.

Comment: So iterating through the fields and then checking for blur event will not validate each input? I am confused :(

Comment: In the code you provided, you iterate through the fields and assign a function to the blur event handler on each field.  When the `blur` event is fired on a field, it triggers `that` event handler, not all three.  In comparison, I assign a function to the blur event handler on each field and within that event handler I inspect the value of each field.  So when the event handler is triggered on one field, all fields are validated.

Comment: ok..So I need to re-write my code like this right?                $('#form1 .required').blur(function(){
var input = $(this);

     input.each(function(){                                         //Check for validations here});

});//blur ends   Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: instead of `var input = $(this);` use `$("input").each(function(){});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41616/discussion-between-user1049057-and-kevin-bowersox)

Comment: Hi Kevin..This logic doesn't seem to work for me :(.. I need to validate only those with required class..Thats y I was first iterating through all required fields and then validating each of them.So how can I do with ur logic? ANy help?

Comment: `$(".required").each(function(){});`

Comment: Hi Kevin..I update my code with ur suggestions..But still its not working..I need to validate only those with required class on blur of the field..and if its error, then have to highlight the field..can u please guide me?

Comment: @user1049057 Post the updated code and I will look at it this evening

Comment: Thanks Kevin for looking into this issue..I updated the question with the new code with ur suggestion. Actually my requirement is I need to get all the required fields in the form and on blur of any of the field, it should validate all the classes it has. If it fails, it should highlight that field. Also the form should be submitted if all the fields are validated correctly. If any of the field validation fails, the form should not be submitted. So on blur of each required fields, I need to validate that field ..

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin for your time.I checked ur fiddle &would need one change in tat.In that,if I dnt giv any value to one field,all the fields are validated at the same time.But i dnt want like that.I want to validate only one field at a time.if I blur first field &if its not validated,only that field should display error(Message is specific to each field &I am getting it frm the title).Similarly it should check for other fields.If any of the field is not validated correctly,then it should not submit the form.Only if all the fields are validated correctly the form should be submitted.Any help?